# Is it possible to use dynamic attributes with Q objects in Django 1.5.1?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.5, django-q

I'm using `django-transmeta` for translated fields and I need to perfom some searches using these translated fields.

Suppose we have a Model with a translatable field called `translated_field`.

In the **first approach** we can think something, as usual, like:

```
Q(translated_field__icontains="some value")  # This fails, as `translated_field` field does not exist
```

The **second approach** would be to hardcode all possible language versions. E.g.:

```
Q(translated_field_en__icontains="some value")  # English version
Q(translated_field_es__icontains="some value")  # Spanish version
# Add as many as available languages
```

This second option seems really hardcoded and I wonder abount a possible **third option** doing something like:

```
Q(getattr("translated_field") + get_language() + "__icontains"="some value")  # pseudocode
```

Or even better... is there any option with **kwargs available using Q objects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the lookup argument name dynamically, use it as a dictionary key, then use `**kwargs` when creating the Q object.

```
field_name_contains = "translated_field" + get_languaage() + "__icontains")
kwargs = {field_name_contains: "some value"}
q = Q(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for! It worked like a charm. Just one note, instead of declaring the var `kwargs` I directly passed the dict like this: `Q(**{field_name_contains: "some value"})` or else it would have been too verbose as there are lots of `elifs` :)